# Can early testing lead to premature optimization?

Tags: testing, optimization

One school of thought that I usually hear is to **Test early, test often**, may it be usability testing or any other kind.

Another statement, which is also generally believed to be true: **Premature optimization is the root of all evil**

That leaves me a bit confused. Should I test early? If I find and fix a problem, is that optimization? Also, is it premature? Should I just use early testing to identify the problems, and then fix them later on?

Please give some guidance regarding these statements.

**How do I know if I'm optimizing prematurely?**

Comment: Testing and optimization are completely different. Testing is about verifying that it executes correctly and produces the proper results. Optimization is about making it more efficient.

Comment: This question might be more appropriate for programmer.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimizing prematurely probably means that you should fix design and/or coding 'issues' at an early stage. If you wait with this, more code will be added and it will be more complicated (and at least time consuming) to improve those issues.

The result is that you - as positive side effects - reduce the number of bugs, not only by optimizing but also later.

You know when you are optimizing prematurely when you improve the structure (either code or design), without changing functionality. For this regression testing can be used:

```
Run tests, all should be ok
Improve code/design
Run tests, all should be ok
```

Of course this only works when you have very good regression tests.

If you mean performance optimmizing, this is completely different and I would advice not to do any performance optimizing unless you run into problems performance wise, or when you know beforehand performance might be an issue. And if the last case is true, it should be part of the design.